# Mostrar um endereço inexistente

Tags: java, algoritmo, busca-binária

Estou fazendo alguns algoritmos em várias linguagens e no Java me deparo com um problema, na minha função **pesquisa_binaria** quando não for achado o valor na lista ele deveria me retornar um **None** ou **null**, porém não consigo colocar nem um dos dois, mas se mando ele retornar 0 funciona, porém esta errado, não quero que ele retorne isso, quero que ele me avise que não foi encontrado o valor inserido no `item`.

```
public class PesquisaBinaria {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] minhaLista = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };

    for (int i : minhaLista) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("Procurando endereço do número o 3 ~: " + pesquisa_binaria(minhaLista, 3));
    System.out.println("Procurando endereço do número o -1 ~:" + pesquisa_binaria(minhaLista, -1));
}

public static int pesquisa_binaria(int lista[], int item) {
    for (int i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {

        int baixo = 0;
        int alto = lista.length - 1;

        while (baixo <= alto) {
            int meio = (baixo + alto) / 2;
            int chute = lista[meio];

            if (chute == item) {
                return meio;
            } else if (chute > item) {
                alto = meio - 1;
            } else {
                baixo = meio + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
} }
```

**o que retorna**

```
    1 3 5 7 9  
Procurando endereço do número o 3 ~: 1
Procurando endereço do número o -1 ~:0
```

Digo **None** pois no Python eu usei ele caso não acha-se o item

Comment: Sua função não pode retornar `null` pois seu retorno é do tipo primitivo `int`. Se deseja retornar null, mude a função para retornar um `Integer`, aí sim, poderá retornar um `null`.

Comment: Acredito que seja porque você ta usando variáveis primitivas e elas não aceitam null tenta utilizar as Wrappers, caso não saiba o que é, veja este link [wrappers em java](https://www.devmedia.com.br/wrappers-em-java-aprenda-como-utilizar/30275)

Answer (score 3):

Você tem que usar Integer, não o tipo primitivo int e sim o  Wrapper, para poder retornar um null, então seu código vai ficar assim:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] minhaLista = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };

    for (int i : minhaLista) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("Procurando endereço do número o 3 ~: " + pesquisaBinaria(minhaLista, 3));
    System.out.println("Procurando endereço do número o -1 ~:" + pesquisaBinaria(minhaLista, -1));

}

//Troquei o nome para ficar na convenção Java
public static Integer pesquisaBinaria(int lista[], int item) {
    for (int i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {

        int baixo = 0;
        int alto = lista.length - 1;

        while (baixo <= alto) {
            int meio = (baixo + alto) / 2;
            int chute = lista[meio];

            if (chute == item) {
                return meio;
            } else if (chute > item) {
                alto = meio - 1;
            } else {
                baixo = meio + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Console:

```
1 3 5 7 9  
Procurando endereço do número o 3 ~: 1
Procurando endereço do número o -1 ~:null
```

Sobre Wrappers:

> Os Wrapper são conhecidos na linguagem Java como classes especiais que
>   possuem métodos capazes de fazer conversões em variáveis primitivas e
>   também de encapsular tipos primitivos para serem trabalhados como
>   objetos, ou seja, é feita um embrulho de streams que são fluxo de
>   dados através de canais.
>
> Sendo assim, existe uma classe Wrapper para cada tipo primitivo
>   identificado pelo mesmo nome do tipo que possui e tendo a primeira
>   letra maiúscula. Essa regra de declaração é aplicada a todos os tipos,
>   exceto aos que são char classificados como Character e boolean como
>   Boolean.

Fonte: http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/3667/classes-wrappers-em-java.aspx

Answer (score 2):

O tipo `int` é um tipo primitivo e não pode retornar `null`.

**Mude o retorno da sua função original:**

`public static int pesquisa_binaria(int lista[], int item)`

**Para:**

`public static Integer pesquisa_binaria(int lista[], int item)`

Agora você pode retornar `null` na lógica da sua função. `Integer` refere-se a um objeto agora, podendo retornar null.